# Original Mbox with protools 8

Tags: pro-tools

I'm running Pro tools 8 on OS X 10.7.3 I have a MBox2 Micro all works fine. But I also have an original Mbox is there anyway to get this working with this version of pro tools and OS X?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the USB-Audio.de ASIO Driver ? There is a version for the MBox (The 2.8.40) that is TORRENT-distributed, it might help you. :)